# How to use embracing in function with select on more than one variable?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I've written a function to `filter()` a data frame on a single variable and to `select()` multiple columns by passing unquoted data-variables, using embracing, as advised in the Programming with dplyr vignette. However, I can't get the function to work without using `enquo()`. Based on the vignette, it seems like I shouldn't need `enquo()`. What am I missing?

```
mydf <- data.frame(myid = 1:6, theid = letters[1:6], data = runif(6), notWanted = rnorm(6))

lookupid <- function(df,var,clmns = NULL,id){
  clmns = enquo(clmns) # Shouldn't need this?
  if(is.null(clmns)){
    filter(df,{{var}} %in% id)
  }
  else{
    filter(df,{{var}} %in% id) %>%
    select({{clmns}})

  }
}

lookupid(mydf,
         var = myid,
         clmns = c(myid,theid,data), 
         id = c(2,4,6))
```

Without `clmns = enquo(clmns)` I get the following error:

```
Error in lookupid(mydf, var = myid, clmns = c(myid, theid, data), id = c(2,  : 
  object 'myid' not found
```

With `clmns = enquo(clmns)` I get the output that I expected:

```
  myid theid      data
1    2     b 0.1243989
2    4     d 0.6992314
3    6     f 0.4314637
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every thing "breaks" because of the `if(is.null(clmns))` check. In order to see if the value is NULL, R needs to evaluate it, but the magic of the dplyr functions that allow you pass in column names unquoted needs those values to be unevaluated. If you need the check, you'll need the explicit coercion to `quosure` via `enquo`. You also want to check for null values using `rlang::quo_is_null` because again it will be an unevaluated NULL epression, not NULL itself. So a more complete version is

```
lookupid <- function(df, var, clmns = NULL,id){
  clmns = enquo(clmns) # Shouldn't need this?
  if(rlang::quo_is_null(clmns)){
    filter(df,{{var}} %in% id)
  }
  else{
    filter(df,{{var}} %in% id) %>%
    select(!!clmns)
  }
}
lookupid(mydf,var = myid,id = c(2,4,6))
#  myid theid      data notWanted
# 1    2     b 0.6072734 0.7755656
# 2    4     d 0.6748970 0.0525449
# 3    6     f 0.6125889 0.3744287
lookupid(mydf, var = myid, clmns = c(myid,theid,data),id = c(2,4,6))
#   myid theid      data
# 1    2     b 0.6072734
# 2    4     d 0.6748970
# 3    6     f 0.6125889
```

If you skip the check for NULL by just checking if the parameter is missing, you can do

```
lookupid <- function(df, var, clmns ,id){
  if(missing(clmns)){
    filter(df,{{var}} %in% id)
  }
  else{
    filter(df,{{var}} %in% id) %>%
    select({{clmns}})

  }
}
# lookupid(mydf,var = myid,id = c(2,4,6))
#   myid theid      data notWanted
# 1    2     b 0.6072734 0.7755656
# 2    4     d 0.6748970 0.0525449
# 3    6     f 0.6125889 0.3744287
lookupid(mydf, var = myid, clmns = c(myid,theid,data),id = c(2,4,6))
#   myid theid      data
# 1    2     b 0.6072734
# 2    4     d 0.6748970
# 3    6     f 0.6125889
```